# Django tag: more than 2 parameters

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there a way to provide more than two parameters to a template tag?

I can do:

```
val1|my_function:val2
```

But where does val3 go?

I tried

```
val1|my_function:val2,val3
```

Edit: val1, val2, val3 are dynamic, meaning that I can access them like so {{val2}}

Comment: Do you mean a template filter? | is the operator for a template filter, not a template tag.

Comment: Really any way that I can get multiple parameters to a function of some sort.

Comment: See @msc's answer below pointing to the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a filter, and a filter can only take one or two arguments. [Writing custom template filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters). If you want a tag that can take multiple arguments, check out [Writing custom template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags).

Answer (score 1):

The templatetag only accept one argument.

There are a few ways to work around this, but I would consider if it is worth it or if you can perhaps change your logic.

The argument needs to be a digit or string.

So this will **NOT** work:

```
val1|func:['a','b']
val1[func:{'a':'b'}
val1|func:('a','b')
```

This will work:

```
val1|func:10
val1|func:10.2
val1|func:"10"
```

What you can do is to send a string that is formatted in a structured way:

```
val1|func:"['a','b']"
```

And then you can create the datatype you need to parse this, but this would be a very ugly solution.

A more clean solution would be with multiple tags:

```
val1|func:'a'|func:'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

For strings you can do:

```
val1|my_function:"val2,val3"
```

and then split:

```
@register.filter()
def my_funtion(val1, args):
    args = [x.strip() for x in args.split(',')]
    #do something
    return value
```

Comment: Even with strings, this doesn't work in my case where val2 and val3 are dynamic. At least I couldn't get it to work. By dynamic Imean that it can be used like so {{val2}}

Comment: The template tag is the best approach then; filters aren't designed to do this kind of things.